# DataRow - How to cancel adding row to datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable, addition, datarow

I have a problem.

I have two loops (one for row, one for column) for creating data in `DataTable`. I want to check if cell is empty for column named `"Name"` and if it is empty just don't add this row. And here is a question: How to cancel adding row?

Got some code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Count(); i++)
{

    cell = data.ElementAt(i);
    DataRow row;
    row = dataTable.NewRow();

    foreach (string column in columns)
    {
        if (row["Name"] == "")
        {
            row = null;
        }
        else
        {
            row[column] = cell;
        }
    }

    if (row != null)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

But after next loop is starting it throws `NullException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Generally I want to add Rows to DataTable only those where value of cell is not empty at column called `"Name"` (i mean where is "").

What is the best way or easiest way to do it right?

Comment: After just creating a row with `dataTable.NewRow()`, you are checking value of it's Name column without pushing some value. Can you please explain this? and on which line you are getting `NullReferenceException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it as:

```
....
    foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            if (row["Name"] == "")
            {
                row = null;
                break; //--> Add this line
            }
            else
            {
                row[column] = cell;
            }
        }
....
```

Comment: If it works please mark it as Accepted answer; and also welcome to Stackoverflow :)